# Angulajs ,Hibernate and Spring MVC -Form Submit with list of objects using http.post

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am very new to angularjs facing some issues to post list of object which inturn has set of objects.Below is my backend bean object strurcture :

```
public class UserBean{

private String userName;

private Set<ContactBean> contactBean= new HashSet<ContactBean>();

private Set<LocationBean> locationBean= new HashSet<LocationBean>();
//getter and setter over here
}

public class ContactBean{

private String contactName;

private String contactPhone;

private String contactEmail;
//getter and setter over here
}

public class LocationBean{

private String country;

private String state;

private String city;
//getter and setter over here

}
```

my controller structure is,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = {RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody String addUser(@RequestBody UserBean userBean){

    return "";
}
```

and my angular js script is

```
var response = $http.post("addUser", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.userBean,$scope.contactBean,$scope.locationBean,)), config);
```

I am setting my data-ng-model like this

```
 data-ng-model="userBean.userName"
 data-ng-model="contactBean.contactName"
 data-ng-model="locationBean.country"
```

How can I set contact and location bean object to UserBean. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you have a `contactBean` and a `locationBean` in the angular code?  Because if not you could just change those to `userBean` and then pass `$scope.userBean` in your http request.

Comment: Yes, a single user can have multiple contacts as well as locations.Hence please suggest a way to post my data from data-ng-model.